# How can I determine if my BindingSource's List has changed?

Tags: winforms, bindingsource

I have a BindingSource which I use to bind to a grid. The binding source itself binds to a custom class. For instance

```
MyGrid.DataSource = MyBindingSource

'Bind the Binding source to data
 For each classInstance as myClass in MyCollection
    MyBindingSource.List.Add(classInstance)
 Next
```

A user may add or delete items to/from this List. My aim is to save this updated List to the database. I need to determine if my binding source's list has changed (i.e. has items added to it, or has items removed from it).

I am aware that I could implement the INotifyPropertyChanged on my custom class, and exploit the OnPropertyChanged event, but my classes' property would never change in my case. The other solution that I can think of is to use the BindingSource's ListChanged event, and maintain a collection of all the added and the deleted rows there. Although this approach may work for me, I reckon its a bit flaky.

Does the binding source or a Collection (such as the IList in my case) provide any other properties that can help me determine the above?